# Ideas on how to animate the showing of a form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, animation

In a Winform application, I'd like to animate the showing of a form a bit like when an email comes in and the notification window raises slowly from the bottom of the task bar.

I've got a few ideas involving timers and resize but they all seem complicated and/or clumsy so I wonder if anybody could suggest a simple way to do this or some magic function I could use to do it automatically.

I'm using VS 2005 and .NET framework 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a sub on the form that does the resizing animation, then create a new thread. Your resizes would have to be done via Invoke() or you will get a Cross Threading Exception.